# Не закрывать tooltip, пока мышка на него наведена?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой HTML:

```
<img src="/img.png" onmouseout="Hide()" onmouseover="Show()" tooltip data-placement="bottom" data-title="Tooltip on right" alt="lol" class="img-thumbnail navbar-left" style="padding: 2px; width: 40px; height: 40px;">
```

Есть такой JS:

```
function Hide() {
    $("[tooltip]").tooltip('hide');
}

function Show() {
    $("[tooltip]").tooltip('show');
}
```

Как сделать в скрипте, чтобы не скрывать тултип, пока мышка на него наведена? (На сам тултип, а не на объект вызываемый его).

Собственно для этого и вынес события наведения и потерю наведения в отдельные функции. Но понятия не имею, как это распространить на сам тултип.. Есть мысли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!

Мы в своем проекте делали с **popover** и если не подойдет (хотя это почти тоже самое) вы сможете взять идею. [Рабочий пример можно посмотреть тут.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pu5xH/)
Итак:

HTML:

```
<div style="height:200px;"></div>
<a href="#" id="element">Это ссылка</a>

<div id="regionPopContent" style="display:none;">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">Ура!</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#element").popover({
    trigger: "manual",
    html: true,
    content: $('#regionPopContent').html()
})
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide")
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip-inner{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #000;
}
```

Надеюсь это вам поможет.