# Как сделать всплывающие подсказки tooltop

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

Не могу сделать всплывающие подсказки tooltop.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-examples

Bootstrap использую именно с этого сайта. Кто может помочь с кодом, написать правильную ссылку и скрипт код что бы все работало?

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день, только что ответил на похожий вопрос, посмотрите тут [Не закрывать tooltip, пока мышка на него наведена?(bootstrap)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/335853/)
Или
[Посмотрите полностью работающий пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/Pu5xH/)

Если вас интересует полный код страницы, то он тут :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>jsFiddle demo by pvkovalev</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style type="text/css">
         .tooltip-inner{
         background-color: transparent !important;
         color: #000;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="height:200px;"></div>
      <a href="#" id="element" data-original-title="" title="">Это ссылка</a>
      <div id="regionPopContent" style="display:none;">
         <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
         <div class="tooltip-inner">Ура!</div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function(){
         $("#element").popover({
             trigger: "manual",
             html: true,
             content: $('#regionPopContent').html()
         })
             .on("mouseenter", function () {
             var _this = this;
             $(this).popover("show");
             $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                 $(_this).popover('hide');
             });
         }).on("mouseleave", function () {
             var _this = this;
             setTimeout(function () {
                 if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                     $(_this).popover("hide")
                 }
             }, 100);
         });
         });         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Надеюсь это вам поможет.

Answer (score 2):

В объекте, над которым хчешь увидеть подсказку пишешь:

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
```

Между тегами `<head></head>`
Напиши функцию инициализации

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

В итоге должно получится что-то вроде:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    $(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Всплывающая подсказка</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В объекте где ты хочешь использовать тултип, напиши атрибут tooltip.
А в head напиши такой код:

```
< script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("[tooltip]").tooltip();
});
</ script>
```